# ElasticSearch query works on dev console but fails in NodeJS instance

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, graphql

I have the following ElasticSearch query that used to retrieve a bunch of pages (search) paginated using a cursor offset.

**Query**

```
GET _search
{
  "search_after": [
    1.8574909,
    "urn:sample/78PsC1EHG6nopQCA/n/749d1ed1-d08d-44a1-abac-9ebad8c76697"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "type": "node"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "query_string": {
                        "query": "a",
                        "fields": [
                          "node.text.string",
                          "node.text.string.english"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "workspace.type": "space"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "workspace.id": [
                        "72MsGpeV9zGu5ytZ"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "workspace.type": "user"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "workspace.id": "8"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "comment.body.text": {},
      "comment.body.text.english": {},
      "node.text.string": {},
      "node.text.string.english": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The query works fine in the dev console and returns a hit with an edge.

**Result**

```
{
  "took" : 136,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "num_reduce_phases" : 2,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 929,
    "successful" : 929,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "sample-development-john",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "urn:sample:d/78PsC1EHG6nopQCA/n/4230ca5a-5e1e-48ee-a70f-95f7b2d09995",
        "_score" : 1.7747711,
        "_source" : {
          "document_id" : "78PsC1EHG6nopQCA",
          "type" : "node",
          "workspace" : {
            "type" : "space",
    ...
```

However, performing the same query through my NodeJS resolver using the Javascript ES API fails when I copy the exact same query in my code.

**SearchResolver.js**

```
// parse the cursor argument for pagination.
search_after = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(args.after, 'base64').toString('ascii'));

 const response: ApiResponse<Taskade.Backend.Elasticsearch.SearchBody> = await client.search({
    index,
    body: {
      search_after: [
        1.8574909,
        'urn:taskade:d/78PsC1EHG6nopQCA/n/749d1ed1-d08d-44a1-abac-9ebad8c76697',
      ],
      sort: [
        {
          _score: {
            order: 'desc',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: {
            order: 'asc',
          },
        },
      ],
      size: 1,
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              bool: {
                should: [
                  {
                    bool: {
                      must: [
                        {
                          term: {
                            type: 'node',
                          },
                        },
                        {
                          query_string: {
                            query: 'a',
                            fields: ['node.text.string', 'node.text.string.english'],
                          },
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
          filter: {
            bool: {
              should: [
                {
                  bool: {
                    must: [
                      {
                        term: {
                          'workspace.type': 'space',
                        },
                      },
                      {
                        terms: {
                          'workspace.id': ['72MsGpeV9zGu5ytZ'],
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                },
                {
                  bool: {
                    must: [
                      {
                        term: {
                          'workspace.type': 'user',
                        },
                      },
                      {
                        term: {
                          'workspace.id': '8',
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
      highlight: {
        fields: {
          'comment.body.text': {},
          'comment.body.text.english': {},
          'node.text.string': {},
          'node.text.string.english': {},
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

**Error**

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "parsing_exception",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "search"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "name": "ResponseError",
          "meta": {
            "body": {
              "error": {
                "root_cause": [
                  {
                    "type": "parsing_exception",
                    "reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [query].",
                    "line": 1,
                    "col": 10
                  }
                ],
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [query].",
                "line": 1,
                "col": 10
              },
              "status": 400
            },
            "statusCode": 400,
            "headers": {
              "date": "Mon, 28 Dec 2020 11:58:05 GMT",
              "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
              "content-length": "239",
              "connection": "keep-alive",
              "access-control-allow-origin": "*"
            },
            "warnings": null,
            "meta": {
              "context": null,
              "request": {
                "params": {
                  "method": "POST",
                  "path": "/sample-development-john/_search",
                  "body": "{\"query\":\"a\",\"size\":1,\"sort\":[{\"_score\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}},{\"_id\":{\"order\":\"desc\"}}],\"search_after\":[1.7747711,\"urn:sample:d/78PsC1EHG6nopQCA/n/4230ca5a-5e1e-48ee-a70f-95f7b2d09995\"]}",
                  "querystring": "",
                  "headers": {
                    "User-Agent": "elasticsearch-js/6.8.7 (darwin 20.2.0-x64; Node.js v10.21.0)",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Content-Length": "182"
                  },
                  "timeout": 30000
                },
                "options": {
                  "warnings": null
                },
                "id": 2
              },
              "name": "elasticsearch-js",
              "connection": {
                "url": "https://search-sample-dev-526nv5wyqxj6ahzcql2cyndz5e.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/",
                "id": "https://search-sample-dev-526nv5wyqxj6ahzcql2cyndz5e.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/",
                "headers": {},
                "deadCount": 0,
                "resurrectTimeout": 0,
                "_openRequests": 0,
                "status": "alive",
                "roles": {
                  "master": true,
                  "data": true,
                  "ingest": true,
                  "ml": false
                }
              },
              "attempts": 0,
              "aborted": false
            }
          },
          "stacktrace": [
            "ResponseError: parsing_exception",
            "    at IncomingMessage.response.on (/Users/john/dev/sample/ft/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:296:25)",
            "    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)",
            "    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)",
            "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)",
            "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "search": null
  }
}
```

This error occurs when I pass the `after` (search_after) parameter to my GraphQL call, despite the values for the query all being **hardcoded** (including `search_after` as seen in the first `Query` snippet).

```
// query will work if `after` is not passed. The values here don't matter since for testing purposes, all values are hardcoded in the resolver.
query {
  search(after: "WzEuODU3NDkwOSwidXJuOnRhc2thZGU6ZC83OFBzQzFFSEc2bm9wUUNBL24vNzQ5ZDFlZDEtZDA4ZC00NGExLWFiYWMtOWViYWQ4Yzc2Njk3Il0=", first:1, filterby:{query:"a"}){
    edges{
      cursor
        node {
...
```

Why is the query working in the dev console, but not working in my resolver when I pass the `after` (search_after after parsing the JSON) params to the GQL call despite the query being hardcoded and **identically similar**.

Comment: The query you're sending via NodeJS seems different according to the error message: `\"query\":\"a\"`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to show the exact query im sending is indeed the same query passed to the dev console.

Comment: Well, still the same query is showing... Are you sure that your query is being built correctly in your GraphQL code? it looks like a variable called `a` is being used verbatim as the query

Comment: Yes, I think the confusion lies within that this is a search query so there is also a param called `query`, in this case the elasticsearch's query is hardcoded to search for documents with the letter `a` in it. This query runs fine in dev console and when the gql call doesn't pass `after` but fails otherwise.

Comment: What I'm saying is that `"{\"query\":\"a\",\"size\":1,\"sort\":[{\...` is not a valid query (i.e. not at all the same that you send in Dev Tools), regardless of the presence of `search_after` or not, so you need to check on how you construct that query inside your NodeJS code, because the problem lies there.